# Prestashop file manager source popup displaying admin panel

Tags: tinymce, prestashop, file-manager

I'm using Prestashop 7.1 and getting an issue with the wysiwyg tiny-mce text editor when trying to upload an image.

I click on 'source' and instead of the file picker, I get the admin dashboard appearing in the iframe window!

The file it seems to be trying to access is:

```
admin******/filemanager/dialog.php
```

however, if I stick a 'die()' at the top of this file, it is not getting there a all. Instead it is getting redirected to:

```
admin******/filemanager/index.php?controller=AdminDashboard&token=6bc7a4670f1f2e71b57ca4b4c4876c51
```

I'd be grateful if anyone has any thoughts or suggestions, as it's really doing my head in now!

I am running it on laravel valet (so nginx) with php 7.1

[image]

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this was because I was running Prestashop on Laravel Valet via this driver: https://github.com/markahesketh/prestashop-driver-laravel-valet

It also was not displaying product images correctly. I suspect this was to do with Valet running Nginx rather than Apache and throwing the Prestashop re-write rules out of whack.

I have since run it on MAMP with Apache and everything is running fine!